# Always show same tag badge in recommedation

Tags: discussion, support, tags, badges

I have asked a question on Meta and here I am able to see two tags in my profile. By default it show [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag in progress but where I have click on setting icon there is only one [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) tag and it is showing in recommendation.

Here is screenshots:
[image]

It is showing on mine profile. And after clicking on setting icon, it is showing:

[image]

But previously it is showing [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. which is not in the list.

1. Why always it is showing [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) tag as **recommended**, even I have selected it?
2. Where is disappear [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag from here?
3. How can I revert back it as it is showing previous?

I am confused. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you ask a question or post an answer with the discussion tag and then delete it?

Comment: @ArunA.S I am asking. see the last 3 point plz.

Comment: your images do not show what you mean, can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: @ArunA.S I have already elaborate the problem, Please see in question.

Comment: Are you saying that some time earlier, you could track the discussion badge but now you can't? , or are you saying that the tag shown is support but the progress shown is of the discussion tag?

Comment: @ArunA.S right. I am saying that. first time it was showing discussion but now there is no discussion anywhere.

Comment: that's why I added my first comment, if one of your previous post had the discussion tag but was deleted and you no longer have any posts with discussion tag ( barring this one, it will take some time for the change to come on your profile ) , then you can't track the tag. You need to have atleast one post with the tag

Comment: @ArunA.S I don't have any previous question or answer. I have only one question before it.

Comment: Your previous question was once tagged discussion, but the tag was removed, which is why you can't track it now.

Answer (score 2):

Your Previous Question on meta, was tagged [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

[The 'unanswered' tab has multiple answered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/292013/revisions)

But later on, the question was edited and the tag was removed, so you can no longer track the badge as you no longer have any posts with the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag

You can only track tag badges for tag's you have posted a question or an answer.

Comment: But soon you will be able to track it because this question is tagged discussion, but it will take some time for your profile to be updated, so wait for some time, and you can track it as well.